# Watch window in VS 2010: string.Format("{0:…}", x) works, but x.ToString("…") triggers exception. Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, tostring, watch

I am in a debugging session in Visual Studio 2010, and the *Watch* window appears to act strangely.

I have a floating-point variable `summe` with a value equal to 1644.48.

- When I add an expression `string.Format("{0:N1}", summe)` to the *Watch* window, it evaluates to `"1'644.5"` (as expected).
- However, the expression `summe.ToString("N1")` causes an "out of range" exception.

[image: Screenshot of the Watch window]

- `summe.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` again works fine (`"1,644.5"`).

  (The *Watch* window reports the "current" thread's `CurrentCulture` as `de-CH`, and `CurrentUICulture` as `de-DE`. But I'm not sure whether the current thread belongs to the Visual Studio debugger, or to the debugged application.)

Does anyone know what is triggering the exception here?

---

Some background information about the debugging session:

- IDE: Visual Studio 2010
- Project type: Silverlight 5 Application
- Build: Debug, Any CPU
- OS: Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bit)
- CPU: Intel Core i7 (64-bit)

Comment: Super weird ... this should work fine ...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Also weird is that the german version of the MSDN does not list that... https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: does it also occure if you'd use summe.ToString("N1",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) ? i dont have a vs 2010 right now

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: It works with the invariant culture specified. I added some details to my question.

Comment: Hehe good guess... still a error in the .netfx 4.0 then... what culture do you use?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: I am not setting the culture explicitly, so I suppose the Silverlight runtime uses the culture settings from the system control panel by default (which should be `de-CH` in my case).

Comment: I guessed that too and can tell you that this does not happen with vs 2012 even if you set the framework to 4.0 ...

Comment: And this is superweird...

Comment: Do you have another machine with vs 2010 at your disposal?

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: Actually, yes, but updating the solution to VS 2013 should be quicker than transferring the solution to a different development machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72846/discussion-between-florian-schmidinger-and-stakx).